Name of $d$-simplex with "orthogonal" complementary subsimplices
Three-dimensional space allows for the following sequence of tetrahedra:

The regular tetrahedron with $d+1$ vertices
The pyramid whose base is a triangle with $d$ vertices centered at $0$ in $\{x_3=0\}$-plane and one vertex $(0,0,1)$
A tetrahedron whose vertices are, on the one hand, $(1,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0)$ as well as, on the other hand, $(0,1,1)$ and $(0,-1,1)$

The construction principle is this:

pick some number $0 \leq m \leq d+1$.
put a regular simplex with $m$ vertices in the subspace of the first $m-1$ coordinates (if any)
put a regular simplex with $d+1-m$ vertices in the subspace of the last $d-m$ coordinates (if any), shifted by $1$ in the single remaining coordinate

In the sequence above, where $d=3$, I have outlined the cases $m=d+1$, $m=d$, and $m=d-1$. The cases $m=d-2$ and $m=0$ are redundant.
To illustrate this once more, consider the full sequence in $d=2$:

The regular triangle centered at the origin
The triangle spanned by $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ as well as $(0,1)$
The triangle spanned by $(0,0)$ as well as $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$
The regular triangle centered at the origin, again

I am wondering whether there is a name for these particular class of simplices and what properties are known about them.

what you are describing essentially is the so called pyramid product, which takes one factor in one subspace and the other factor in an orthogonal, but affinely shifted subspace, connecting the various elements lacingly.
If both the factors are regular simplices of dimensions $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively, which have both the same edge size (if applicable), and furthermore the affine shift was chosen such that the lacing edges too all have the same size, then the outcome of this pyramid product would be a regular simplex of dimension $D=d_1+d_2+1$.
Restricting this pyramid product onto the simplices, as you did, simply means to orient the total $D$-dimensional simplex with a $d_1$-dimensional element first. Thereby the opposite element then would have $d_2$ dimensions and gets positioned somewhere behind.
Assuming again regularity of all those simplices then the height-to-edge ratio for a $d_1$-dimensional element first orientation would become
$$\sqrt{\frac{D+1}{2(d_1+1)(d_2+1)}}$$
--- rk
